# Is is possible to delete photos from cameraRoll programmatically...?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to delete the photos which are saved in camera-roll is it supported in iphone ..? any info..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is supported by iOS.  Here's a link to the developer documentation for the Assets Library:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html

I don't see any affordances for deleting photos.

Comment: It's definately not supported at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

This is supported in iOS8, but will always ask the user for permission:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetChangeRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHAssetChangeRequest/deleteAssets: