# How to delete selected photos from the Gallery in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

Is it possible to delete photos within an iPhone Application? My application select the pictures from the gallery on the iPhone and I would like to allow the user to delete these pictures (through the application) as well.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen, you can copy files from the gallery into your application's file system sandbox, where you can do anything you want with them. However, your application can't modify files outside the sandbox. This includes files in the gallery.

[As this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142061/is-is-possible-to-delete-photos-from-cameraroll-programmatically), there doesn't appear to be a method defined for deleting photos there.