# Remove photo from album or library in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cordova

It is possible to remove selected photo from album or photos library  in IOS ?

If yes how ??

I need the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short it is **NOT** possible to delete photo from album so best way is stop fighting with it just read for more information 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1413776?start=0&tstart=0

Also check this

[Is is possible to delete photos from cameraRoll programmatically...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142061/is-is-possible-to-delete-photos-from-cameraroll-programmatically)